# What is the best word to describe a thing that is not clear to us?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to say `The search behaviour of the algorithm is not clear to us`. I want to tell that we don't really know the search behaves. So far I only know the word `unclear` such that:

```
The search behaviour of the algorithm is unclear
```

I am not sure if there is a better word

Comment: Is it "search behaviour of the algorithm" or "behaviour of the search algorithm"? That is, is the algorithm specifically for searching or is it just the search behaviour of a bigger algorithm (that does other things, too) that is unclear? And are you just asking for it to be explained better (or at all)? If so, "unclear" is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Uncertain is perhaps better, to indicate you've got some idea. Longer shots, depending on context, might be:

Uncorroborated
Ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

"Unclear" is a reasonable word to use. You might also consider "opaque" if you want to communicate not only that it's unclear to you, but that it's generally unclear, or you could use "uncertain" if it's strictly unknown how the algorithm will behave.

However I think I would suggest reformulating your sentence to something closer to your description of what you want to say rather than looking for a particular single word choice. "The search behaviour of the algorithm is not clear to us" is fine, but you could also consider something like "We don't know what the search behaviour of this algorithm is", or "It is not clear to me how this search algorithm will behave".

If you are particularly interested in certain aspects of the behaviour of the algorithm, i.e. performance, optimality, or stability, you might be better to highlight the particular area that is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The word "**abstruse**" seems to fit best. It means *difficult to understand*. It is, however, not very common in usage. The "abstruse" thesaurus link below provides some alternatives.

Perhaps "**obscure**", or something similar, would be a better word choice to convey the meaning of "unclear".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/abstruse

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/obscure

https://www.freethesaurus.com/abstruse

Answer (score 0):

You can use '**vague'**. Like the words mentioned above, it is also the synonym of '**unclear'.**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vague

One of the examples given on the link

**At the moment, the text is rather vague; we need greater precision and emphasis.
From Europarl Parallel Corpus - English**